# Yii2: check exist ActiveRecord model in database

Tags: php, yii2

How to check existence of model in DB?
In Yii 1 version it was so
`User::model()->exist()`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Yii2 you can add `exists()` to your query chain:

```
User::find()
    ->where( [ 'id' => 1 ] )
    ->exists();
```

(The generated SQL looks like this: `` SELECT 1 FROM `tbl_user` WHERE `id`=1 ``.)

Here is [`Query->exists()`from Yii2 source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/d7ffda020b391b2fecf167a6f7e7a718bfc311fc/framework/db/Query.php#L410-L426):

```
/**
 * Returns a value indicating whether the query result contains any row of data.
 * @param Connection $db the database connection used to generate the SQL statement.
 * If this parameter is not given, the `db` application component will be used.
 * @return bool whether the query result contains any row of data.
 */
public function exists($db = null)
{
    if ($this->emulateExecution) {
        return false;
    }
    $command = $this->createCommand($db);
    $params = $command->params;
    $command->setSql($command->db->getQueryBuilder()->selectExists($command->getSql()));
    $command->bindValues($params);
    return (bool) $command->queryScalar();
}
```

Comment: mine does not working in where clause, what do I have to do?

Comment: Does it return a true/false or 1/0? I would like to return a boolean.

Comment: `* @return boolean whether the query result contains any row of data.`

Comment: Thank you @ippi
  Up +

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Mastersettings::find()->where(['id'=>1,'status'=>1])->exists())
{                    
  //....... Your code Here ......
}
```

http://yii2ideas.blogspot.in/2017/06/yii2-database-operations.html