# Check table exists

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, dao

I need to check if a table exists in a database. I currently develop using Yii2.

My case is a bit different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362301/yii2-check-exist-activerecord-model-in-database) because the table to be checked is not (and can not be) a model.

I have tried `(new \yii\db\Query())->select('*')->from($mysticTable)->exists());`

The above throws a `yii\db\Exception` because, according to question linked above, the `yii\db\Query()` class tries to `->queryScalar()` when asked if `->exists()`. Invariably, this method checks if the result-set exists.

How do I check if a table exists?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For Yii2 you can use:

```
$tableSchema = Yii::$app->db->schema->getTableSchema('tableName');
```

If the table does not exist, it will return `null`, so you can check returned value for being `null`:

```
if ($tableSchema === null) {
    // Table does not exist
}
```

You can find this method in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-schema.html#getTableSchema%28%29-detail).

Comment: And for yii1: use `getTable` instead of `getTableSchema`.

Answer (score 0):

Good that you get an exception. Simply parse the exception message. You would get a very very specific message and SQL error code for missing table.

That is what I do when checking e.g. IF an error was due to something that can be recovered, say a broken connection, versus some other error.

OR I see that many people have pointed out much more direct ways of getting that information.

Answer (score 0):

A spin off [@msfoster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31671304/393021) got me closer to a solution in [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2)

```
/**
 * @param $tableName
 * @param $db string as config option of a database connection
 * @return bool table exists in schema
 */
private function tableExists($tableName, $db = null)
{
    if ($db)
        $dbConnect = \Yii::$app->get($db);
    else
        $dbConnect = \Yii::$app->get('db');

    if (!($dbConnect instanceof \yii\db\Connection))
        throw new \yii\base\InvalidParamException;

    return in_array($tableName, $dbConnect->schema->getTableNames());
}
```

This also serves multiple databases.

Comment: if someone could put this into the yii2 source. that would be nice

Comment: Did you see my answer? You can do it with framework built-in methods, no need to write own methods to achieve that.

Comment: @arogachev there are no such straightforward built-in methods in Yii 2. And, I have multiple databases so `Yii::$app->db` isn't sufficient.