# Show error message when detected duplicate entry

Tags: php, yii2

I wanted to let the system to show error message when detect duplicated entry of full_name column without applying unique in the full_name column from public function rules() in model.

My code is like this :

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
         $model->full_name =  $model->first_name .'' .  $model->last_name ;
        
        $name = StudentInfo::find()->select('full_name')->where(['full_name'=> $model->full_name]);
       
       
        
        if($name ==  $model->full_name ){
           
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Same student name is detected');</script>";
            
        }
        else{
        $model->status ="Active";
        $model->call_format = Countries::find()->select('phonecode')->where(['name'=> $model->country]);
        $model->date_created = new Expression('NOW()');
        
        $user->user_type ='student';
        $user->user_name = $model->full_name;
        $user->user_status = $model->status;
        $user->authKey = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(10);
        $user->accessToken = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(10);
        $user->save();
        $model->save();
        
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }
```

But it shows error like :missing required parameters: id. When i apply model->save(false) ,it seems that the sql statement wont run because of duplicate entry in full_name column. How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a construct `exists()` for such a purposes (see [Yii2: check exist ActiveRecord model in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362301/yii2-check-exist-activerecord-model-in-database) ).

```
        if(StudentInfo::find()->where(['full_name'=> $model->full_name])->exists()){  
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Same student name is detected');</script>";           
        }
        else{...}
```

it generates the `EXISTS` query, which is faster and you don't have to load all the data from DB.

If you don't have such a column in your table, then check it by the first/last name.

Comment: Ok thanks, i also using other methods like count() to detect duplicate entry. Both also works and i try to remove some statement like user = new users() first to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

**change it:**

```
 $name = StudentInfo::find()->select('full_name')->where(['full_name'=> $model->full_name]);
```

**To:**

```
$name = StudentInfo::find()->select('full_name')->where(['full_name'=> $model->full_name])->one();
```

Also, if you use the `select()` method, to use the `update(`) and `save()` or `updateCounters()` ... methods, you need the row ID in the same query.

**Example**:
`->select('id')`  or `->select(['id', 'full_name'])`

**info**: Multi-parameter is an array in `select()`

Answer (score 0):

```
:missing required parameters: id
```

could mean that it couldn't find id, not by duplicate entry in full_name column. please check again

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code.

```php
$name = StudentInfo::find()->select('full_name')->where(['full_name'=> $model->full_name]);
```

When this line is executed the `$name` variable will contain instance of `yii\db\ActiveQuery`. You want to call some method, that will actually execute your query and return result.

You can use `scalar()` to get the selected value. In that case the `$name` will contain the content of `full_name` column from result.

```php
$name = StudentInfo::find()
    ->select('full_name')
    ->where(['full_name'=> $model->full_name])
    ->scalar();
```

Or you can use `count()` to get the number of rows that match condition. In that case you may leave out the `select()` method call but you will need to modify your condition

```php
$count = StudentInfo::find()
    ->where(['full_name'=> $model->full_name])
    ->count();
if ($count > 0) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Same student name is detected');</script>";
} else {
  // ...
}
```

The other problem is that you are not checking whether your `$model->save()` was successful. If your `$model` is new instance and the `id` attribute is auto-generated then when `$model->save` fails the `$model->id` is empty and then you are trying to redirect user to view with empty id.
Your code should look like this:

```
if ($user->save() && $model->save()) {
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

If the save fails because of validation the validation errors will be stored in models and if you are using `ActiveForm` widget the errors will be displayed. If you are not using ActiveForm you should do something to tell user that operation failed.

Since you are saving two different models you might want to consider use of transactions to prevent a situations where `$user` model is saved but save of `$model` fails.

Comment: I am sorry, but the `count()` solution isn't appropriate for this usecase, because you just need the boolean value, not the number. The exists operator should be used.